# Finding a Data pattern

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining, visualization, algorithms

I am new to this data science field.

I have data of points in 3D space and each point "helps" a metric. I have the sets of points and corresponding metrics.

Data might look like:

```
[Pt_set1_1], [Pt_set1_2], [Pt_set1_3], ..., [Pt_set1_20], Metric1, Metric2, Metric3  
[Pt_set2_1], [Pt_set2_2], [Pt_set2_3], ..., [Pt_set2_20], Metric1, Metric2, Metric3
```

I want to identify which points help which metrics. Is this problem solvable with the data science algorithms. Which algorithm would help me? Please let me know. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "helps a metric"? What objective function are you trying minimize exactly?

Comment: Rotation in x, y, z. I am not minimizing, I am trying to find a pattern on which points are helping the metrics.

Comment: When you say "helping" you probably, implicitly, mean "minimize something". Think about how you can formulate your problem more mathematically, and people on this site will have a chance at answering it. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you have a bunch of sets of 20 3D points, and for each set of points you have three metrics associated with it.

Yes, it's definitely possible to learn which points are most predictive for each metric. I would recommend that you split your data such that the point sets are in one numpy array which looks like

```
x1_1, y1_1, z1_1, x1_2, y1_2, z1_2, ..., x1_20, y1_20, z1_20
x2_1, y2_1, z2_1, x2_2, y2_2, z2_2, ..., x2_20, y2_20, z2_20
...
```

and then create one 1D numpy array for each of your metrics which contain the value of each metric for every point set. Then, you can use something like a [`RandomForestRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) to try to predict the metrics individually from the points. Once you have the random forest trained with the `fit(X, y)` method, you can extract the importances of each coordinate in the points by getting the `feature_importances_`. For example, something like this:

```
rf1 = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000)
rf1.fit(points, metric1)
print(rf1.feature_importances_)

rf2 = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000)
rf2.fit(points, metric2)
print(rf2.feature_importances_)

rf3 = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000)
rf3.fit(points, metric3)
print(rf3.feature_importances_)
```

Hope this points you in the right direction!

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The print for rf1.feature_importances_ prints all [0. 0. 0. ...] Am I missing anything?